# Execute a Python script with Crontab

Tags: python, cron

I'm trying to execute a python script using crontab. I want to run this script every 2 hours. I use:

```
export EDITOR=nano
crontab -e
```

then:

```
0 */2 * * * cd /Users/myname/Desktop/CoronaFR/ && /opt/anaconda3/bin/python3 CoronaFR.py
```

But it doesn’t work. Any idea? Maybe a path problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove `cd` command and directly call the script by this command:

```
0 */2 * * * /opt/anaconda3/bin/python3 /Users/myname/Desktop/CoronaFR/CoronaFR.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`0 */2 * * *  /opt/anaconda3/bin/python3 /full/path/to_the_script/CoronaFR.py`